# can we customize class , module names for archetype project?

Tags: maven-archetype, archetypes

I have created a archetype project. But I want some dynamic naming way. For example I can give the class name as per my wish while generating the new project, how can I achieve that ?

Is it possible to fix the issue or is there any other way to fix that issue ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.